# Erro na Stored Procedure do Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela de ligações que todo mês preciso apagar para serem incluídos novos dados. Fiz uma stored procedure para automatizar esse processo. Essa tabela tem cerca de 3 milhões de linhas em um período mensal. Isso pode aumentar ou diminuir um pouco a cada mês.

Fiz o seguinte código abaixo, porém o Mysql está retornando um erro que eu não estou conseguindo identificar.

O erro:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@delete_ligacoes:loop SET @linhas := (select id from ligacoes where id >= @min' at line 9

A linha 9:

> @delete_ligacoes: loop

Se alguém puder me ajudar...

```
BEGIN
SET @minimo = 0;

@delete_ligacoes: loop
    SET @linhas := (select id from ligacoes where id >= @minimo order by id limit 1000, 1);
    prepare stmt from @linhas;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;

    if @linhas is null then
        leave @delete_ligacoes;
    end if;

    SET @queryDelete := (DELETE FROM `ligacoes` WHERE id >= @minimo AND id < @linhas);
    prepare stmt1 from @queryDelete;
    execute stmt1;
    deallocate prepare stmt1;

    SET @minimo = @linhas;
end loop;

    SET @varDelete := (DELETE FROM `ligacoes` WHERE id >= @minimo);
    prepare stmt2 from @varDelete;
    execute stmt2;
    deallocate prepare stmt2;
END;
```

Comment: A primeira vista, creio que você precise tirar o @ de @delete_ligacoes.

Comment: você poderia esperar o @EdgarMunizBerlinck postar a resposta e aceitar a resposta dele.

Comment: Eu não vi a resposta dele! Descobri pesquisando no google! Eu teria perfeitamente esperado. Depois que eu postei aí vi a resposta...

Comment: @CristianoPires pode marcar a sua resposta como a solução. Não me importo com os pontos, só quero ajudar a comunidade. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Resolvi o problema.

Esta linha: `@delete_ligacoes: loop` não pode ter o arroba '@' no loop. Eu retirei o arroba e funcionou perfeitamente.

Obrigado!